# jackson jersey json : serializing date from java to json

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

my JSON output looks like:

```
 "company":{"companyId": 0, "companyName": "OnTarget Technologies", "companyTypeId": 0, "address": null,…},
    "projectParentId": 24,
    "projectAddress":{"addressId": 26, "address1": "4750 59th street", "address2": "Apt 9C", "city": "Woodside",…},
    "taskList":[{"projectTaskId": 9, "title": "Installation of Lights", "description": "Installation of lights",…],
    "projects": null,
    "startDate": 1424322000000,
    "endDate": 1427515200000,
    "projectImagePath": null
    },
    {"projectId": 26, "projectName"
```

the data type in database for startDate and endDate is Datetime

i get the datetime when serialized in json as a long integer.

how do i convert it to a readable format while serializing like in a 
format MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss

I created a provider but its not working

here's my provider:

```
@Component
@Provider
public class MyObjectMapper implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public MyObjectMapper() {
        this.mapper = createObjectMapper();
    }

    private static ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
        mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        return mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
        return this.mapper;
    }
}
```

I am using jacskon jersey 2.x, spring mysql database

any idea is appreciated.

thanks
Sanjeev

Comment: which version of jackson are you using?

Comment: How about this: get long value from object mapping but convert to Date just before inserting to database

Comment: i am using jackson 2.4.3.

Comment: @EfeKahraman this is during sending JSON back to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jackson 2.4 (so slight difference in how ObjectMapper is configured) you have the correct config (see below)

Are you sure that your object mapper as configured in your provider is being used?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;

public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void foo() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
        mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

        final String output = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Bar(new Date(10000000L)));
        assertThat(output, containsString("01-01-1970 03:46:40"));
    }

    private static class Bar {
        @JsonProperty("date")
        private Date date;

        public Bar() {
        }

        public Bar(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also have this: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency> in my pom.xml. is this causing any issue?

Comment: Weird; the ObjectMapper configuration in my answer is for jackson 2, but the configuration style in your provider seems to be for jackson 1. Which version of jackson-databind are you using?

Comment: its 2.4.3 . And btw whats the diff in using org.codehaus.* vs com.fasterxml.* . my code compiles iwth both but your example is using com.fasterxml.*

Comment: I changed to com.fasterxml.* and it solved it. Awesome. thanks.